# NameOwnerChanged events sent to null destination every second

Tags: i3, d-bus

Running `dbus-monitor --system`, shows a lot of these events:

```
signal time=1567100862.252579 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=467227 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
  string ":1.381958"
  string ":1.381958"
  string ""
signal time=1567100863.303822 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=467228 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
  string ":1.381959"
  string ""
  string ":1.381959"
signal time=1567100863.311397 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=467229 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
  string ":1.381959"
  string ":1.381959"
  string ""
signal time=1567100863.315985 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=467230 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
  string ":1.381960"
  string ""
  string ":1.381960"
signal time=1567100863.322069 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=(null destination) serial=467231 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameOwnerChanged
  string ":1.381960"
  string ":1.381960"
  string ""
```

There's a new event coming in about every second.

I noticed that these events do not occur before calling `startx`.

I'm on Arch Linux 5.2.9 running i3.

Is this some sort of timer or heartbeat DBus uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for these events was my i3 status line. It's defined in `~/.config/i3/config`

```
status_command while ~/.config/i3/status.sh; do sleep 1; done
```

Inside `status.sh`, I call [`upower`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPower) to get the current battery information of the laptop.

Removing the calls to `upower` caused the `NameOwnerChanged` events to cease.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my webcam had been troubled for a while. When I checked syslog, I could see the webcam being detected as keyboard and then being failed from being attached. I disconnected the webcam wire and it fixed the problem.